# HTML - Choose Between Languages

Tags: html, box

I am horribly new in HTML and I want to implement a source code on HTML, which allows the user to choose content in different languages (basically EN and GER).

So far I found this to give the user the opportunity of choosing a language.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SEVER['PHP_SELF'] ; ?>" method="POST">
     <label><input type="radio" value="de" name="language"> DE</label>
     <label><input type="radio" value="en" name="language"> EN</label>
<input type="submit" value="Ok" />
</form>
```

How can I add the text now?

So the user should be able to choose a language by putting a tick in a box or whatever and then only see the text in the chosen language.

Could u guys show me how to connect the selectable box with the texts?

Regards! Sascha

Comment: just in php/html or with js? you can read the value of the radio with "$_POST['language']" and switch the language with "if($_POST['language'] == 'en') {echo 'english';} elseif($_POST['language'] == 'de'){echo 'deutsch';}"

Comment: What technologies are you using? server-side or client-side?

Comment: HTML only. I have an IBM WCM and want to put the contents into the Text Editor by using source code ...

Comment: So basically I just want the user to put a tick in a box (EN or GER) and then the edited text shows up. That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Is your question its just how to change text in different language [this](http://www.bitrepository.com/php-how-to-add-multi-language-support-to-a-website.html) link could be a good starting point.

Comment: well that may be a step too far. I have the IBM web content managing system and to edit the contents I can also insert source code. The source code I posted gives the opportunity of putting ticks into boxes. Now I want to connect these boxes with the outcome, that there show up texts in different languages (if TICK in GER - BOX --> show german text. and so on ...)